# XenServer virtual network firewall

Tags: virtualization, firewall, xenserver

We are setting up XenServer machine with several VMs for our ecommerce business. We are intending to distribute services across several VMs (1 for web, 1 billing, 1 email, etc.)

The XenServer machine has 2 NICs.

My question is should we be using a public IP for each VM and rely on IPTables for firewall security, or should 1 NIC to devoted to management and the other for a virtualised firewall application such as Untangle, and route the VMs through there?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using xen for quite a while. I think you go with multiple public ip address so you can quickly monitor each service that those vms run.

Also a note: I have virtualized a production mail server and it turned out bad and sluggish.

Comment: Thanks jmazaredo. The server only has 1 NIC but multiple IPs. I assume I can set this up in XenServer rather than relying on a firewall?

Comment: Yes. You can setup this on the xenserver or directly on the vms vi bridge.